# How can I identify which variables were accessed (read and/or write) per instruction from the trace?

Tags: python, stack-trace, trace

I am trying to build dependency graphs from a trace of Python code. (I understand that I will not have complete information) Consider the code snippet for example:

```
L1: a = 1
L2: b = 2
L3: c = a + b 
L4: d = a + 2 + c
```

The dependency graph will have one node per line and contain the following edges (apologies for not providing an image of the graph). Each edge implies a data dependence. For example, in L3 `c` is calculated using `a`, hence the edge L1 -> L3

```
L1 -> L3
L2 -> L3
L1 -> L4
L3 -> L4
```

I am planning to use `sys.settrace(trace)`. The function trace is being called for every instruction. What I need to identify is which variables are read and/or written in each instruction. With that (partial) information, I can build the dependency graph (correct only for that particular trace).

Within the trace function, I can access the stack frame and the local variables. By keeping track of the value of each variable, I can check the writes to a variable. However, it is very costly. But I don't find anything within the stack frame that can help me to identify the reads.

To sum up, my queries are:

1. How do I identify reads and/or writes to variables?
2. Is my choice of using `sys.settrace()` right, or should I check some different tool?

Edit:
I understand that using trace only gives me an incomplete scenario. However, a dependency graph-from from a trace will do for my case.

Comment: Note that monitoring reads will **not** give you a complete or stable dependency graph that you can rely on.  eg `x = a if b else c` will tell you that `{a, b} -> x` when `b` is `True` but `{b, c} -> x` when `b` is `False`

Comment: Yes! However, I couldn't any static method/tools for building the graph. So, I am trying to use the trace to build a graph that is sound only for a given input. Newbie here in program analysis. Any suggestion? Also, the resources for python seem to be more scarce than languages like C.

Comment: This is generally a debugger function; building a DAG from source code usually involves a sophisticated parser for the language.  What are you trying to do that requires this functionality?  You already have the read=RHS, write=LHS idea for simple assignment statements, but we have no idea how deep you need to go with this.  For instance, would you need to track a class variable that's a list of references?

Comment: The read=RHS, write=LHS was just a simple example to explain my question. Basically, I want to have as few assumptions as possible. For example, if a line contains a function call to a separate module that changes reads/updates a varaible, i need to identify that information, even if I need to go very deep.

Comment: However, for now, even a heads-up to how I can do this within a single file will do.

Comment: So you want to write a python parser. Look at the ast and dis modules. Actually running the program will give you incomplete information.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks. In my case, even the incomplete information might work. Do you have any suggestions on how to do it using the trace results? Also, I stumbled upon the dis module a few days ago. I wanted to try out my options with trace at first. However, I will look into the dis module now, that I hit a wall with the trace option.